# ggplot stat_sum() producing unneccesary legend entries

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data in a data.table structured as follows:

```
> head(dt)
   V1         V2
1: 11   702.3312
2: 12 17207.1137
3:  4 10886.1332
4: 33  5618.6494
5: 11  3511.6559
6: 15  8779.1397
```

I am trying to create scatterplot of `V1` vs `V2` such that if two points overlap, then it produces a larger point.

This is simple with ggplot using `stat_sum()`. My code is as follows:

```
plt<-ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=V2, y=V1, group=V1))+theme_bw()
plt<-plt+stat_sum(aes(size=..n..), alpha=0.4)  
plt
```

The plot I am getting is:
[image]

Notice that even though the points at a location are added to produce integers, the legend has entries for 1.25, 1.5, 1.75.

How can I modify the code to produce legend entries only for the integers which actually exist on the plot (in this case 1 and 2)?

*Note1:* I am using `aes(size=..n..)`, as according to the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_sum.html), it uses sum, instead of proportions

*Note2:* My actual dataset is much larger, so i don't want to manually change the legend entries

**Data for reproduction**

```
> dput(dt)
structure(list(V1 = c(28, 38, 26, 13, 32, 9, 4, 23, 46, 4, 26, 
5, 2, 3, 3, 25, 8, 23, 23, 2, 30, 8, 7, 33, 1, 1, 13, 27, 44, 
40, 19, 12, 16, 22, 30, 18, 5, 22, 10, 11, 2, 15, 25, 14, 7, 
1, 4, 16, 6, 5), V2 = c(3511.65586098655, 8427.97406636771, 17558.2793049327, 
2809.32468878923, 10183.801996861, 4916.31820538118, 702.331172197322, 
2106.99351659193, 21069.9351659193, 3862.82144708518, 1053.49675829597, 
1053.49675829596, 2458.15910269058, 4916.31820538118, 5267.48379147983, 
3160.49027488788, 1053.49675829595, 2106.99351659193, 7023.3117219731, 
1404.66234439462, 702.3311721973, 3862.8214470852, 3160.49027488788, 
16855.9481327354, 702.331172197302, 2809.32468878925, 2458.15910269058, 
16504.7825466368, 16855.9481327354, 9481.47082466369, 3511.65586098653, 
4213.98703318385, 5267.48379147981, 5267.48379147983, 5618.64937757847, 
16855.9481327354, 4916.31820538117, 16504.7825466368, 2106.99351659193, 
4916.31820538116, 3160.4902748879, 3511.65586098655, 3160.49027488788, 
2809.32468878925, 4916.31820538116, 5618.64937757848, 702.331172197322, 
3160.4902748879, 8427.97406636773, 1755.82793049328)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000028b0788>)
```

**Further Explanation**

Unlike the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110104/only-display-specific-labels-of-a-ggplot-legend), where the aim is to highlight only a specific type of point in the graph using legend, in my question, I want to stop `stat_sum()` from producing entries in the legend which do not correspond to any element of the graph. As I had highlighted in my question, since the number of points at each location (i.e. overlapping points) is added, it is not possible that a point on the graph represents 1.25/1.5/1.75 entries from the table. Each point on the graph can only represent 1: Only one point at that (x,y) without an overlap, or, integers greater than 1: Representing how many points overlapped at that particular (x,y) location.

Comment: Have a look at the arguments to `?scale_size`.

Comment: @Axeman: `scale_size` does not seem to solve the problem. It only allows me to specify the range of the size of the points.

Comment: [You also have `limits`, `breaks` and `labels`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_size.html).

Comment: @Axeman: Using `scale_size` along with breaks work! Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only display specific labels of a ggplot legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110104/only-display-specific-labels-of-a-ggplot-legend)

Comment: I have added ab explanation aiming to highlight why this question is not a duplicate

Comment: I think the problem isn't specific to stat_sum, it's just about showing only some of the legend entries. There might be a more suitable dupe target though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te problem lies with the ggplot2 assuming the size attribute to be a continuous variable. Converting it forcefully into factor will solve the problem.

Since in your case always the size variable is always integer you can just use `as.factor` in the `size` parameter inside `aes` of the `stat_sum` function and you will get the desired result.

The below code

```
plt <- ggplot(data=dt, aes(x=V2, y=V1, group=V1))+theme_bw()
plt <- plt + stat_sum(aes(size=as.factor(..n..)), alpha=0.4)  
plt <- plt + labs(size='n')
plt
```

gives me this
[image: The final output]